# Read csv column

Tags: python, csv

Using csv show count of total errors and warnings for different dates shorted by errors

My csv file format:

```
Date    Level    Message
2016-04-23 04:44:43.472132    [debug]    email error
2016-04-23 04:44:43.472132   [debug]     error
2016-04-23 04:44:43.472132   [warning]   debug error
2016-04-23 04:44:43.472132   [warning]   warning message
```

Expected output Format:

```
Date               Errors      Warnings
2015-11-23          45            320
2015-11-22          20            200
```

Comment: are you asking us to just write the code for you? (That won't happen) What have you tried?

Comment: Is it csv format? @Display Name: His codes had only spaces (without tabs) before your **edit**.

Comment: I just remove trailing `<br>` which he added. All indention and whitespace was there before.

Comment: Ah ok. i saw it. Sorry!

Comment: @Sunny: please read the example here [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader)

Answer (score 0):

```
logs = {}
with open("log.csv") as csv_file:
    for line in csv_file:
        date, time, type, message = line.split(None, 4)
        log_by_date = logs.setdefault(date, {})
        log_by_date[type] = log_by_date.get(type, 0) + 1

print(logs)
```

This should work...

Comment: No this is not working. got an error more than 3 values to unpack

Comment: Sorry, typo. Try again please.